# Сборка CAFFE в Windows C++ VS Project

Tags: c++, машинное-обучение

Я пытаюсь выполнить сборку Caffe под Windows для дальнейшего использования в своём C++ проекте. Следую [инструкции на GitHub](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows).

У меня установлена Visual Studio 2017. Путь к файлу cl.exe следующий: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\ cl.exe`

Установлен так же CMake версии 3.14.3.

При выполнении скрипта build_win.cmd возникает ошибка:

> CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 14 2017 Win64.

Полный вывод:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\caffe>scripts\build_win.cmd
Системе не удается найти указанный диск.
Системе не удается найти указанный диск.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 0
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 14 2017 Win64"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 1
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 2
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 0
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 0
INFO: ============================================================
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 14 2017 Win64

Generators
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
* Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.

ERROR: Configure failed
```

Содержимое скрипта: https://pastebin.com/XqZfP18u

Как исправить ошибку?

P.S.: Выполняю CPU-only сборку. Никаких CUDA не устанавливал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

небольшая опечатка в скрипте, надо исправить версию студии:

```
    if "%MSVC_VERSION%"=="14" (
    set CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 14 2017 Win64
)
```

на

```
    if "%MSVC_VERSION%"=="14" (
    set CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
)
```

Важно! Библиотеку можно собрать только Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Спасибо. Это проблема решилась, но возникла новая. Видимо, сборка предполагается с использованием VS 2015 (всё таки и в инструкции именно эта версия указывается), т.к. скрипт пишет: `CMake Error: Error: generator : Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
Does not match the generator used previously: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.`

Comment: Возможно как то выполнить сбоку не устанавливая студию 2015 года?

Comment: Да, как я уже писал, надо заменить вот эту строчку:.      if NOT DEFINED MSVC_VERSION set MSVC_VERSION=15

Comment: Я заменил. `INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 15
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` - часть вывода.

Comment: обновил ответ с точным указанием строк, где поправить

Comment: У меня так и было: https://pastebin.com/SVi8kSzY

Comment: Может быть сами попробуете собрать по инструкции, и скажите что я мог сделать не так? Там вроде делов то не так много (если у вас Windows и установлена студия 2015+). Буду очень вам благодарен.

Comment: К сожалению сам использую VS 2015, для моих нужд её хватает. Судя по сообщению в ошибке Вам нужно удалить файлы, сгенерированные cmake'ом ранее и перезапустить скрипт. Или лучше всё удалить, заново оаспаковать, внести изменения в сборочный скрипт и запустить.

Comment: _"К сожалению сам использую VS 2015"_ - так это подходит. _"Вам нужно удалить файлы, сгенерированные cmake'ом ранее и перезапустить скрипт"_ - попробую.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93765/discussion-between-alexey-nikolaev-and-d-stark).

Comment: Какие тесты можно провести, чтобы определить корректно ли выполнена сборка?

Comment: после конфигурации проекта открыть солюшн `caffe-windows\scripts\build\Caffe.sln` и выполнить команду Build для проекта `runtest`. В окне Output можно будет увидеть результаты прогона unit-тестов: `3>  [==========] 1106 tests from 150 test cases ran. (43389 ms total)
3>  [  PASSED  ] 1106 tests.`

Comment: Я перед сборкой в скрипте build_win.cmd указал `RUN_TEST=1`. Это не эквивалентно тому что выполняет `runtest`? Все тесты, кстати, прошли и тогда и сейчас успешно. Я написал в чате подробнее о новой проблеме.